# How to delete new pointer that declared on function parameters?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

My class have member function that take pointer of it's own type as it's argument.

When I do this:

```
Object* obj1 = new Object();
Object* obj2 = new Object();

obj1->add_child(obj2)

delete obj1;
delete obj2;
obj1 = NULL;
obj2 = NULL;
```

and run `valgrind`, the report says:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
  total heap usage: 6 allocs, 5 frees, 73,098 bytes allocated

LEAK SUMMARY:
   definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

I read [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857638/4019871) says that `still reachable` is fine, no leak. Then, when I try this:

```
Object* obj = new Object();

obj1->add_child(new Object());

delete obj;
obj = NULL;
```

`valgrind`'s report says:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
    in use at exit: 72,877 bytes in 3 blocks
  total heap usage: 6 allocs, 3 frees, 73,098 bytes allocated

LEAK SUMMARY:
   definitely lost: 144 bytes in 1 blocks
   indirectly lost: 29 bytes in 1 blocks
     possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
   still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
        suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

It's obvious that I didn't delete the `new Object()` pointer that passed as an argument. So, how do I delete that pointer?

**DETAILED UPDATE**

definition of `add_child(Object* obj)`:

```
void add_child(Object* obj) {

    container.add_child(obj);
}
```

`container` is a member of `Object` which is an instance of template class.

```
Container<Object> container;
```

The `Container` definition is:

```
template<class T>
class Container {
public:
    void add_child(const std::string& key, T* child) {
        childrens.insert(std::pair<std::string,T*>(key, child));
    }
private:
    std::multimap<std::string,T*> childrens;
}
```

Then, the childrens is actually a `std::multimap`.

I hope this not too long for just a question.

Comment: Where do you store the pointer? That's what you delete.

Comment: it's impossible to tell without knowing the definition of the `Object` class. You should really be using smart pointers (e. g. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`) instead, though.

Comment: Notice that it says `72,704 bytes in 1 blocks`, which doesn't match the size of the lost pointers in the second program. Do you have an idea what could be a such a large object in your program? (since it says "1 block", it's probably an array, given such a large size)

Comment: Updated. That's how I stored the pointer.

Comment: What version of gcc do you use? [If it's 5.1, then you may suffer from this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393229/new-libstdc-of-gcc5-1-may-allocate-large-heap-memory)

Comment: @milleniumbug those bytes is refer to `malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)` which is called by `(in /usr/lib/ld-2.21.so)` in the end of it's calling chain.

Comment: @milleniumbug I see .. My gcc is version 5.1. It's a bug then. I'm glad to know that, even not related to my main question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a clear and consistent choice about who **owns** pointers. If you decide that `add_child` **takes ownership,** then the caller should expect that they don't need to delete the pointer passed in. If you decide that `add_child` **does not take ownership,** then the caller retains ownership and deletes the pointer.

You can make `Object` take ownership, so its destructor deletes all the child pointers that have been added to it. Then your first example should read

```
Object* obj1 = new Object();
Object* obj2 = new Object();

obj1->add_child(obj2);

delete obj1; // also deletes obj2 automatically
```

and your second:

```
Object* obj = new Object();

obj->add_child(new Object());

delete obj; // automatically deletes the unnamed pointer passed in on previous line
```

If you don't want `Object` to take ownership, then you have a problem, since you have no way of deleting the `new Object()` in the context of the caller.

If you use smart pointers, managing ownership becomes much easier. `add_child` can take a `std::unique_ptr<Object>` argument.

```
auto obj1 = std::make_unique<Object>();
auto obj2 = std::make_unique<Object>();
obj1->add_child(std::move(obj2)); // obj1 takes ownership
// both pointers automatically deleted at scope exit

auto obj = std::make_unique<Object>();
obj->add_child(std::make_unique<Object>());
// both pointers automatically deleted at scope exit
```

Answer (score 2):

Once the function call is finished, you no longer have the pointer that `new` created. If the function you called doesn't delete the pointer, then you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The valgrind report about your still reachable memory block isn't your fault - [it's the bug in gcc 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393229/new-libstdc-of-gcc5-1-may-allocate-large-heap-memory).

How did I come up with this:

The block size was very large (`72704`) and didn't match the size of allocated objects, so next I tried to divide `72704` by `144` and `29` to see if it's an array of these objects.

But it wasn't since neither `72704`, nor `72704-4`, nor `72704-8` (array, array + 32-bit integer to store the size, array + 64-bit integer to store the size) weren't divisible. So then I googled "`72,704 still reachable`", which showed the mentioned question.

The other answerers' suggestions to use smart pointers (like `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) are sound, and I too recommend using them.