# Heap allocation for std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, valgrind, stdarray

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548254/does-stdarray-guarantee-allocation-on-the-stack-only) `std::array` is allocated on the stack. However when using it together with `Valgrind` it shows me a heap allocation, even for elements which are allocated on the stack. Is this a false positive or real?

Here follow two `mwe` to illustrate the behavior.

**No heap:**

The following code:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int*, 1> map;
    int value = 0;
}
```

Produces the expected following `Valgrind` output:

```
==14425== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14425==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14425==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
```

**With heap:**

However if I try this code:

```
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int*, 1> map;
    int value = 0;

    map.at(0) = &value;
}
```

`Valgrind` gives me

```
==14539== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14539==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==14539==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated
==14539== 
==14539== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==14539==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14539==    by 0x4EC3EFF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==14539==    by 0x40106B9: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:72)
==14539==    by 0x40107CA: call_init (dl-init.c:30)
==14539==    by 0x40107CA: _dl_init (dl-init.c:120)
==14539==    by 0x4000C69: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so)
==14539==
```

Added compile settings:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O0 valgrind.cpp -o valgrind_build -I ../fake -I ../src
valgrind --track-origins=yes --dsymutil=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./valgrind_build

valgrind --version
valgrind-3.11.0

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: What compiler and what flags? All this should be removed in an optimized build anyway.

Comment: could be a false positive, its hard to come up  with a usage of this snippet that wont leave you with a dangling pointer in the array (or using heap allocation)

Comment: "*According to this question std::array is allocated on the stack.*" No, that's not what it says. What it says is that `std::array` is not allowed to perform heap allocation. If you allocate `array` *itself* on the heap, then the array will be on the heap.

Comment: Your second example look like what you'd see from the global object in the standard library (like `cin` and `cout`).

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775034/valgrind-error-in-use-at-exit-72-704-bytes-c-initialization-list-weirdness-w

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code

```
map.at(0) = &value;
```

introduces bounds checking, which might in turn need to use stuff allocated dynamically (e.g. from the `<iostream>` library).

You may try again with

```
map[0] = &value;
```

which doesn't apply bound checks.

Comment: Wow, didn't think about bound checking introducing dynamic allocation. But you are correct.

Comment: Yet another reason to not automatically use `at()`.

Comment: The only dynamically allocated memory I could see `at()` using is when throwing a `std::out_of_range` exception. If you don't go out of bounds, no exception is thrown. So, what else could be using dynamic allocation in this case? Maybe some kind of static initialization even if the exception is not thrown?

Comment: @remy _"Maybe some kind of static initialization even if the exception is not thrown?"_ Sure, that is what I was thinking of.